# PHP - XHTML linebreaks <br />

Tags: php, xhtml

Here is the code:

```
if (isset($_POST['state']) && count($err) > 0) {
    echo "<p>";
    array_walk($err, create_function('&$value', 'printf("$value<br />");'));
    echo "<br /><a href=\"/#contacto\">Volver</a></p>";
}
```

The problem:

The code works as expected, but it insists on printing linebreaks like `<br>`. Refusing to print them like `<br />`, as if it didn't like the XHTML guidelines.
Any other forward slash `/` (in a closing tag) is printed correctly.

I have already tried `nl2br()` with the second parameter set to 'true'. I've tried escaping them with a backslash `\` (and then the backslash is printed but not the forward slash). I've tried escaping them with another forward slash (curiously enough it didn't comment the rest of the line), and passed the strings through `echo`, `printf`, and `trim` to no avail.

Can anyone tell me what is going on?

Comment: Are you not sure that is your browser which remove the `/`?

Comment: Where do you see that the line breaks are `<br>` instead of `<br/>`? In the browser's View Source, or Firebug, or... ?

Comment: Ok... now I feel dumb... I noticed that the source view is as it should be on IE, FF and Chrome. Firebug and the Chrome console are the ones eating the slashes. Found the guilty.

Comment: Don't use printf in this way. While safe in PHP (except a notice) it would create a huge security hole e.g. in C since people could inject `%s` and then cause bad memory ready.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To simplify your logic, you could just use:

```
echo implode('<br />', $err);
```

If you've tried all those techniques to no avail, are you sure there's an issue with your code? Maybe you should try viewing your code using another browser, or even with some command-line tool such as curl:

```bsh
curl http://www.example.com/
```

Comment: I didn't think of `echo implode`! Thank you! By the way, as per the comments above, Firebug and the Chrome where causing the trouble...